# String tokenization python

Tags: python, string, tokenize

I wanted to split a string in python.

```
s= "ot.jpg/n"
```

I used `str.split()` but it gives me `['ot.jpg']`. I want to get `ot.jpg` without brackets.

Comment: Did you maybe confuse "split" and "strip"?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `str.strip()` to get rid of the newline. If you need to use `split`, it returns a list. To get the nth item from a list, index the list: `['foo', 'bar'][n]`.

Incidentally, naming your string `str` is a bad idea, since it shadows the built-in `str` function.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the `split()` method is always a list -- in this case, it's given you a single-element list `theList = ['ot.jpg']`. Like any list, you get what you want out of it by indexing it:

`myString = theList[0]`

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want replace.

```
s= "ot.jpg/n".replace("/n", "")
"ot.jpg"
```